# "Failed to Fetch Update" error when opening app center on newly installed Juno

Tags: release-juno, appcenter

I just installed Juno and trying to open the app center and this thing popped out, how to fix it?

```
Failed to Fetch Update

This may have been caused by external, manually added software repositories or a corrupted sources file.

    E: http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 Packages is not (yet) available (File has unexpected size (34849 != 35207). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.28.4.44 80]
    Hashes of expected file:
     - Filesize:35207 [weak]
     - SHA256:d60095dd675259874ea62c6dc1c64d84dd687bc88e2eff9e675199a32a340e44
     - SHA1:e4891242386e767555495f17f9a413ca3f36a316 [weak]
     - MD5Sum:ed4f8383338719748b96e18b3444933b [weak]
    Release file created at: Thu, 03 Jan 2019 13:31:35 +0000
    )
    E: http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata is not (yet) available ()
    E: http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons is not (yet) available ()
    E: http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons is not (yet) available ()
    E: http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons is not (yet) available ()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have no network connection. Get a wired connection (Ethernet) and open [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter), it will be able to fetch updates.

**Tip:** You may face problem with WiFi. If you do, click on the `Installed` tab from [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) and install `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver by clicking `free`. Your [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) will be working again.